# I want to convert a negative int/ double value into positive of the same

Tags: int, double

I want to convert a negative int/ double value into positive of the same, and use it for further calculations..i tried using %2 but the value turns out to be -0.0. It would be a great help if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: multiply it by negative one?

Comment: and you want to do this in a programming language? Asking because there is no direct way to do this in INTERCAL.

Comment: @diggersworld Haha.. Thank you..! It worked..! never crossed my mind that the ans would be so simple..! :D
Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @PascalCuoq i wanted to do it Java.. sorry for not specifying it. I got the ans the negative one works. Thanks tho..! :)

Comment: In Java and other C-like language, you can use the unary minux construction: `y = - x;`. If this is to use as part of a wider expression, parentheses may be necessary and help with readability: `y = (- x) / 2;`

Answer (score 31):

In `Dart` you can do like this

```
value.abs()
```

In `Kotlin` you can do like this

```
value.absoluteValue
```

In `JavaScript` you can do like this

```
Math.abs(value)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you only want to change negative numbers you could do:

```
if(num < 0)
    num *= -1;
```

I'm just reiterating what diggersworld commented...

Comment: You can do it with a division too: `num /= -1;`. I cannot think of a more expensive solution at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin you can do it like this:

```
yourValue.absoluteValue
```

Or smth like this:

```
 abs(yourValue: Double)
```

Also, check this out for more info: 
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/absolute-value.html

Answer (score 1):

For Dart

Example, replace "-50" with your value or variable.

```
print((-50).abs());
```